# showing record in text view using sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i have created this method in dbHelper class.
I am calling this method from mainActivity using onClickListener to show column 1 of each row one by one by changing cursor position.
i need to move the cursor to next row each time the button is clicked to show the string in Column1 in a textView.
i am new to android and programming too, so please bear with me.

```
public String nextData() {
        String nQuote = "";
        int i=0;
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_IQ };
        Cursor resultSet = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        resultSet.movetoPostion(i);
        if (i==0||i!=resultSet.getcount()){
            resultSet.moveToNext();
            nQuote = resultSet.getString(1);
            i++;
        }
        return nQuote;
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this,

```
public String nextData(int position) {
    String nQuote = "";
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_IQ};
    Cursor resultSet = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (position >= 0 && position < resultSet.getCount()) {
        resultSet.moveToPosition(position);
        nQuote = resultSet.getString(1);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return nQuote;
}
```